# Header preprocessor unique IDs generation C++

Tags: c++, header, guid

**Some code I stumbled upon today:**

```
#ifndef EVENTHANDLER_H_62B23520_7C8E_11DE_8A39_0800200C9A66
#define EVENTHANDLER_H_62B23520_7C8E_11DE_8A39_0800200C9A66
```

Under normal circumstances, you'd write `#ifndef EVENTHANDLER_H` and `#define EVENTHANDLER_H`. But, instead here they have appended `_62B23520_7C8E_11DE_8A39_0800200C9A66` which looks like some unique **GUID** string.

- **Q1:** *Why do they append the unique random numeric string?*
- **Q2:** *It does NOT look like the typical MS generated GUID, so what tool is used?*

---

**EDIT:** Response to comments, I am fully aware of `#pragma once` this does not concern that aspect. But rather, the style of doing something like the authors have done.

**Code:** https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp/blob/new-api/include/yaml-cpp/eventhandler.h

---

Comment: Any clue which IDE created that file?

Comment: It is a guid, just in a slightly different string format. "#pragma once" should to the trick usually. If you have visual studio installed there is "create guid" tool. For C++ in the windows API there is [`::CoCreateGuid`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-cocreateguid) and for linux there is [`libguid`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/libuuid). And online there is : https://guidgenerator.com/

Comment: As for "why is it done like this": it eliminates the chance of collisions with another file that may be called `eventhandler.h` as well.

Comment: The whole idea is that GUID values are globally unique identifiers. There are algorithms that guarantee that they can be uniquely generated (using some unique propeties of your computer and time information). Side note many compilers also support `#pragma once` to achieve the same result.

Comment: A possibility is to some random number generator.... In practice, large random numbers (e.g. on 128 bits, then in hexa) collide rarely. You probably might script that easily on Linux and GNU emacs.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch No they don't exactly do that read this (if you're interested) : [GUIDs are globally unique, but substrings of GUIDs aren’t](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080627-00/?p=21823)

Comment: To be sure, you'd have to ask the author of that code.  I concur with Botje's assessment that it is to avoid header guard collisions.  Header guards are *supposed* to be unique, and *supposed* to be an internal implementation detail.  But they do cause unavoidable macro-space identifier pollution.  Seems the author was trying to make the guard pollution unlikely to interact with anything else.